# How to limit password length in text mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to fix the input length, so every user can only enter 4 characters in **text mesh**.

I am calculating the length of the user input on mouse UP but I can't find any property where I can limit the maximum length.

```
TextMesh totaldigit = new TextMesh();     

void OnMouseUp()
{
    PlayerCode += gameObject.name;
    totalDigits += 1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more information please? Where is this script attached? What is `PlayerCode`?

Comment: @playerCode is string input

Comment: You could try to add the following condition : `if( PlayerCode.Length >= 4 ) return ;` as the first line of the `OnMouseUp` function

Comment: @Hellium Yes i do the same I dont know how i  miss simple thing 
you can post as answer i will accept It

Comment: @Hellium Although Thank for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a simple condition inside the `OnMouseUp` function checking the current length of the string before concatenating the new digit :

```
TextMesh totaldigit = new TextMesh ();     
void OnMouseUp()
{
    if( PlayerCode.Length >= 4 )
        return ;

    PlayerCode += gameObject.name;
    totalDigits += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i also Reached Same Point Thanks Again :) for your time